# Get version of item given url powershell

Tags: document-library, powershell, versioning, item

I'm writing a script which gets the version of an item given the URL. However I can't seem to get the versions.

```
$objFile = $web.GetFile($sitecollection+/ZB/Forms/DispForm.aspx?ID=5266)
        Write-host $objFile.MinorVersion
```

however this doesn't seem to bring back the right results.
What is the right way to get the version based on the url being `dispformid=x`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This gives you the string label of the version:

```
$objFile.UIVersionLabel
```

This gives you the Major version:

```
$objFile.MajorVersion
```

This gives you the Minor version:

```
$objFile.MinorVersion
```

**Edit:**
The code above works with documents. The following will work with list items:

Assuming you have the id of your list item (in your example that is: "x"), you can create the $list object, get the list item and get the version of the item.

```
$webUrl = "http://SiteUrl";
$web = Get-SPWeb $webUrl;
$list = $web.Lists["ZB"]
$list.GetItemById(x).Versions[0].VersionLabel
```